# Maven assembly plugin: run only one descriptor

Tags: plugins, maven-2, assemblies, maven-descriptor

I have a project which has several custom descriptors written for the assembly plugin. Is there a way to run only one of those descriptors at a time instead of the whole bunch? I tried using the descriptors switch as documented [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly-mojo.html), passing in the full path to the one descriptor that I wanted to run, but instead it's running all of the descriptors in my app's main pom file, seeming to ignore the switch I specified.

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce, what version of the plugin are you using, how is it configured exactly, can you provide your `pom.xml`. Please, help the readers a bit...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do so, is by using [Maven Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Define some profiles in your pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>profile-1</id>
    <properties>
      <assembly-config>assem1.xml</assembly-config>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>profile-2</id>
    <properties>
      <assembly-config>assem2.xml</assembly-config>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then you use that particular property for the configuration of the assembly plugin:

```
 ...
 <descriptor>src/main/assembly/${assembly-config}</descriptor>
 ...
```

Then run your maven build with the -P option: `mvn -P profile-1 compile`

So, summarized, if you choose a profile at buildtime, the property assembly-config will be set depending on the defined profile. The assembly configuration depends in that case on the chosen profile.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I was hoping it wouldn't come to that, but I can't see any other way to do it either. Thanks.